# Long running scripts in Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line

I am running a script on Windows command line that takes multiple hours to finish executing. During this time, I am required to keep my computer open or the script stops. I was wondering if there are any tools that I can use which would keep the script running even if I put my computer to sleep (or shut the computer down). Thanks!

Comment: No, of course not.

Comment: I think the tool that you are looking for is something that keeps the computer awake running the script instead

Answer (score 0):

If computer is put to sleep or shut down, programs cannot run on it by definition of these states. Possible workarounds might include:

1. Running script on a permanently running remote machine (i.e. server)
2. Preventing computer to go to sleep